# App Engine application not visible on dashboard of Google Apps users

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm working on a Google App Engine application and want to bind it to my Google Apps environment. This works perfect for my admin account of Google Apps. When I login to Google Apps with this account, I see the added application on my dashboard.

But, when I login to the Google Apps environment (using https://www.google.com/a/mydomain.com/) with a regular user account then the app is not visible. I expected the app to be available for all users just like the Market Place apps.

For the binding I followed this link:
http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=nl&answer=91077

I also tried the "add more services" function on the dashboard of the administrator.

Comment: Thanks for your quick comment. The application is available for all users by accessing the direct link (myapp.mydomain.com). Thats great. What I want to achieve is that all the users have the application icon/link on there Google Apps environment (https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/mydomain.com/UserHub).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just gave up searching for a solution and started to add the application to the MarketPlace for public use. Before submit I was asked to test the app on my domain. So I did and saw the app was added to my Google Apps dashboard and also to all the users :D

So no manipulation of the manifest is needed and it saved me $100.

Answer (score 1):

App Engine apps are not shown to users of the Apps domain. If you want to do that, you need to add your app to the Apps Marketplace.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a private section on the Marketplace or are all apps available for public.